# create map for indoor navigation

Tags: android, dictionary, xml-parsing, osmdroid, indoor-positioning-system

I have created maps using josm editor. However, I have no idea how to put it into function in my android application. The file generated from josm editor is xml or osm. Is it xml parser is needed?

Anyone used sails MRE to create indoor navigation application before? 
http://support.sailstech.com/kb/tutorial/newbie-guide-create-your-first-indoor-lbs-project

Is it a must to render my map created from josm using their map render editor? and how to retrieve the map if I use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to generate the tiles(images) and providing it to your android system:

- modify osm data(using JOSM or QGIS) and export it (as .osm or .shp)
- import the data in a tile generator(TileMill for example)
- export the images(as a folder of .png or as .mbtiles file)
- use osmdroid lib to read these tile sources in your android application

Comment: I tried to import the osm data in TileMill. However, it showed this problem "Could not create datasource. No plugin found for type 'osm' (searched in: C:\Program Files (x86)\TileMill-v0.10.1\tilemill\node_modules\mapnik\lib\mapnik\lib\mapnik\input)"

Comment: If you need help on another subject, i suggest you to post another question, you will get more visibility and therefore more help. If you need more details about the answer,please ask. If the answer is sufficient, please mark it as resolved.

Comment: That's why I am asking for more details to import the osm data in a tile generator. Appreciate your help.